# How to redirect to view without action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to redirect to a view, but there is no action method. Because it is not required.

Why I want to do that. Because You can delete a file(DeleteFile) or you can delete a folder(DeleteFolder).

I have this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteFile(string designId, int fileId)
        {
            DeleteFileModel DeleteFile = new DeleteFileModel();
            TemplateLibraryEntry entry = GetTemplateLibraryEntry(designId, customerSchema);
            FileTree tree = CreateTree(designId, entry.FilePath);
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tree.Files[fileId].FullPath);
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tree.Files[fileId].FullPath);

            if (directoryInfo.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory) {
                //Url.Action(designId, "DeleteFolder");


                string directoryName = tree.Files[fileId].FileName;
                DeleteFile.DesignId = designId;
                DeleteFile.FileName = directoryName;
                DeleteFile.Id = fileId;
                DeleteFile.ModificationDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;

                DeleteFile.RelativePath = fileInfo.Directory.Name + "/" + directoryName;
                AddFileExplorerBreadCrumb(designId);
            }
            else {

                string fileName = tree.Files[fileId].FileName;
                DeleteFile.DesignId = designId;
                DeleteFile.FileName = fileName;
                DeleteFile.Id = fileId;
                DeleteFile.ModificationDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
                DeleteFile.FileSize = fileInfo.Length;
                DeleteFile.RelativePath = fileInfo.Directory.Name + "/" + fileName;

                AddFileExplorerBreadCrumb(designId);
            }

            return View(DeleteFile);
        }
```

So if it is a directory a user want to delete, then it goed to view: DeleteFolder and if the user want to delete a file, then it goes to: DeleteFile. But how to do that?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have two diffrent views for delete file and delete directory

Comment: yes, because there are different properties on the views

Answer (score 2):

You need to put return statement in if and else part

```
If( your directory delete condition){
Your directory delete logic
return view("deletedirectory.cshtml");
}
else{
//File delete logic
return view("deletefile.cshtml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to show a sort of confirmation page after a 'delete' action is called, and you want to specify which page (file vs directory) without having to create an action for each.

You can do this by specifying the name of the view you want in the View() method.

```
return View("DeleteFileConfirmation.cshtml", model)
```

or

```
return View("DeleteFolderConfirmation.cshtml", model)
```